# Whats the average duration of English phonemes?

Tags: phonemes

I found this paper on phoneme length in the Polish language, but I can't see to find anything like this for English.

Polish Phoneme Length Paper:
http://www.dsp.agh.edu.pl/_media/pl:ltc-001-ziolko.pdf